# Mpdf + Angular : Http failure during parsing

Tags: php, angular5, mpdf

First, i know that this issue is common, and plenty of post speak about this kind of error. I've read them all, and tried many things and it still doesn't work.

Let me detail, my issue. So i'm working with Angular 5 + Php on an app. 
So with this app i'm creating some pdf, using [Mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/). I've got two ways of producing a pdf. One is created a file and then send it by mail, and the other one, is allowing to download it directly by the user.

For the first way, it's working very well. No problem with it. For the second way, everything is pretty much the same except that the [Output function](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) from Mpdf. Instead of

```
$mpdf->Output($docName, 'F');
```

i'm using :

```
$mpdf->Output($docName, 'I'); //for Inline cf link above
```

which is supposed to open the user prompt to allow downloading. 
And in return i get this error : [image]

So here is my **service.ts** interacting with the php script :

```
export class MailService {
  urlPost = '/crapo-app/api/mail/postMail.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendMailAndPdfToPrtcpt(mailAndHtmlReport: MailAndHtmlReport): Observable<any> {
    console.log('SendMailtoPartcpt in svc', mailAndHtmlReport);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.urlPost, mailAndHtmlReport);
  }
}
```

Here is the **php script** :

```
<?php
  require_once('./../fonctions.php');
  require_once('./../pdfy/pdfy.php');

  try {
      // this is an object which contains also the report name adn the pdf instructions
      $mailAndHtmlReport = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

      pdfyThis($mailAndHtmlReport->htmlReport, $mailAndHtmlReport->docName, $mailAndHtmlReport->pdfInstruction);

      //send mail here

      $return = 'Les mails ont bien été envoyés aux destinataires choisis';

      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($return);
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
      $errorMsg = date('d/m/Y') . ";"
          . date('H:i:s') . " : Erreur lors de l'envoi de mail: "
          . $e->getMessage() . ". Fichier " .$mailAndHtmlReport->docName. "fonctions.php, Fonction composePdf \r\n";
      erreur($errorMsg);
  };
```

Here is the **php function** used (which is called by the main php script) :

```
<?php
session_start();
  require_once('C:\xampp5.6\php\lib\mpdf\mpdf.php');


     function pdfyThis($htmlReport, $docName, $pdfUse) {
       try{
        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start();

        $mpdf = new mPDF('c','', 12, 'calibri', 0, 0, 55, 20, 0, 0, 'P');

        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->SetTitle($docName);
        $mpdf->SetAuthor("Smthg");
        $stylesheet = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/somepath');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img style="vertical-align: top;" src="'.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/somepath" />','O',true);

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlReport);

        if ($pdfUse === 'download') {
            $docName = $docName.".pdf";
            $mpdf->Output($docName, 'I');
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        else if ($pdfUse === 'sendByMail') {
            $docName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/somepath".$docName.".pdf";
            $mpdf->Output($docName, 'F');
            ob_end_flush();
        }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $errorMsg = date('d/m/Y') .";".date('H:i:s')." : Erreur lors de la composition du PDF : ".$e->getMessage().". Fichier ".scriptsDir."fonctions.php, Fonction pdythis\r\n";
        erreur($errorMsg);
      }
    }
```

So yes the error message is pretty clear, yet, i haven't found out where is the issue. The script with the output 'F' is working and not with 'I'. I guess i'm missing something...If anyone has an idea i'm taking it. i can put more code if needed.